# How to run 'Call in Editor' Functions that are implemented in Level Blueprints?

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, blueprints, editors

I have a `Blueprint Function` within a `Level Blueprint`, marked as `Call In Editor`.

[image]

How can I run `CallInEditor` functions in Level Blueprints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. Direct quote from the offical docs on "
Calling Blueprints in the Editor"

> The steps described below work for any Blueprint class that you can place in a Level—that is, any class that derives directly or indirectly from Actor.

Source:
https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Editor/ScriptingAndAutomation/Blueprints/CallInEditor/index.html

If possible I'd suggest placing an empty actor into your level and creating your function there and make it editor-callable. This should work fine and won't render any problems as far as I can assess the situation.

Comment: Damn - I wanted to automate the filling of an array within my level blueprint

Comment: You can use blutility